# TinyMCE removes urls from images links

Tags: tinymce

I got php script which uses TinyMCE as a text editor, and when I'm linking some images it changes this url https://yourdomain.com/assests/image.png to /assests/image.png any ideas how I can fix this?

I've tried surfing the net but no answers, thank you for answers.